# Is there a way to change the URL of a page while sending it?

Tags: html, http

Let's say that I have a webpage called `page.html`, and on the page is a button.  That button sends a request to the server to retrieve `page.html?cmd=Button&value=42`.  But all I want the user to actually see when the page loads is `page.html`, with the updated content.

I can do that in two steps by having the backend update the data appropriately and then return a redirect to plain `page.html`, but that means that the user's browser has to hit the server twice for each request.  Is there any way to have it update the data and render the page, and send something (in the header, most likely) so that it will only display in the browser as the page name, without the query string?

Answer (score 2):

Other than your suggestion of updating then reloading, you should use HTTP POST (with the button inside a form with its method attribute set to "post" and your cmd and value variables in hidden fields), or an ajax-type background request.

Comment: Yes, use POST as your request type to update your data, and then redirect to "page.html" to display the updated data.